# vertical scrolling bar for a table using html

Tags: html, css

I want to fixe a height for my html table in the web page and if it pass the height automatically a vertical scrolling bar is shown.

please help.

Comment: You should probably clarify whether you want the header and/or footer cells of the table to remain fixed whilst the rest is scrollable, or not.  Having them fixed is the more popular request, but significantly trickier.

Answer (score 34):

It's not the table that scrolls, it is the div behind it.

```
<div style="height:200px; overflow-y: scroll;">
  <table>
   ....
  </table>
</div>
```

use `overflow-y` if you only want  a vertical scroll bar and `overflow` if you want both a vertical and horizontal.

**Note:** setting an overflow attribute to scroll will always display the scrollbars.  If you want the horizontal/vertical scrollbars to only show up when needed, use `auto`.

Comment: What's the div for? Why don't you merely scroll the table?

Comment: but what about the header? <thead> even this will scroll

Answer (score 7):

You'd want to place the table inside of a div like so:

```
<div style="height: 400px; overflow: auto;">
    <!-- Html Elements --!>
</div>
```

Anything inside that div, when it goes over 400px in height, will overflow and a scrollbar will be shown.

Comment: What's the div for? Why don't you merely scroll the table?

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a table element...

You'd have to wrap the table element in a container. A div with the class name `table-container` would suffice. You would then go ahead to give the container a fixed height and make the table element's width to be `100%`

```css
.table-container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 800px;
  overflow: auto;
 }
 
 .table-container table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table>A table</table>
</div>
```