# how to make the text in a single cell of the table scroll vertically

Tags: css, html, scroll

I tried:

```
overflow:scroll;
```

In the `div` which did not worked.

Is there any other work around to achieve this scrolling?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897967/vertical-scrolling-bar-for-a-table-using-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must give the div height and width to get this to work, see here:

http://jsbin.com/ukesif/1/